# What is linkbaiting?

Tags: seo, backlinks

I have been wandering around some SEO sites this evening and have been seeing this term *linkbaiting*. The word *bait* kind of makes it not sound so great.

What exactly is linkbaiting and how does it differ from article marketing? From the gist of some of these descriptions I'm seeing, this is something fairly new, but it seems almost identical to article marketing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not new. It means creating content that people want to link to. Infographics can be good link bait. The proper way to get links it to have something worth linking to. By creating something unique, or something very informative, you create link bait. 
Here is a good example of a very well written article that is link bait: http://www.seobook.com/economics-of-content-farms.

More info: http://www.ericward.com/linkbait-services.html.

Answer (score 10):

It is simply wording a link in such a way (using controversial or inquisitive/mysterious) language that makes it hard for readers not to click on the link. I don't agree with @joe that it's simply content that's worth linking to, its more than that - it's the emotive appeal. The final destination doesn't actually have to be link-worthy, but because the "hook" was so well crafted, then the "bait" was taken and the reader ended where they normally might not have.

E.g.: [StackExchange now pays $20 for every correct answer!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_bait)

Comment: @Mike Hudson: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the example you gave looks like click-bait.

Comment: @Programming Enthusiast I do believe you're right.

Answer (score 5):

Matt Cutts defines link bait as anything "interesting enough to catch people's attention".

Further answer of your question: http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-linkbait-and-linkbaiting/.